# Как производятся выплаты Google Play?

Tags: google-play, платежи, монетизация, android-billing

Произвожу монетизацию приложения и хотелось бы иметь какую либо информацию на случай выплат.  Насколько я понял, вся прибыль отражается в "Аккаунте продавца" => "Подписки и услуги". А детали в "Способ получения дохода" и вот тут самое интересное.

1. Можно воспользоваться обычной `visa` в национальной валюте, или можно открывать в банке и валютный счет? Я так понял, что необходим отдельный валютный счёт, т.к. нужны данные `SWIFT`.
2. Возможно, использование системы `Payoneer` более выгодно?
3. Возможно ли в будущем сменить реквизиты выплат на другое юридическое лицо (карту)?
4. Возможно, есть какая-то форма или система для минимизации потерь на налогах и переводах?

Comment: с удовольствием почитаю ответ, мне тоже интересно) плюсую